# Offline mode for Android app using the Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, offline-caching

Is there a way to use the offline mode in Android apps using the Google Maps API?

Any direction to a tutorial or source code would be a massive help. I've been searching for hours without any luck. I know Google has released a way of using maps offline, but is it available for Android developers?

Comment: It is not available for third party app developers. There are certain ways you can force cacheing but they are in violation of google's terms of service.

Comment: What about preloading maps before entering low internet areas?

Comment: I have the custom tiles, need to show them but getTile() does not get called on the first launch. I need to show custom tiles on first launch in airplane mode. can somebody help? @PropK

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[See this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles) or [this one](https://github.com/cocoahero/android-gmaps-addons).   Basically you just create your own tileprovider and access tiles locally. It is totally doable with the v2 API. [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider)

There's some false information floating around out there that the v2 Google Maps API requires an Internet connection. There was a but where the API would require a single access after app install to verify with Google Play services, but I believe this has been fixed.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056156/using-the-android-google-maps-api-v2-as-a-viewer-of-offline-tiles-is-it-possibl) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4817).

Comment: @Simon 2nd link is shifted [here](https://github.com/cocoahero/android-gmaps-addons)

Comment: I have the custom tiles, need to show them but getTile() does not get called on the first launch. I need to show custom tiles on first launch in airplane mode. can somebody help? @AjithPandian

Comment: You need to connect to the maps API  at least once to make cache of tiles. GoogleMaps  API does not alow storing tiles outside service. You can see this here [https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions] refer 10.5.d.