# Storing Google Maps data for use offline with my Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2, offlineapps

I've created an Android application that uses Google Maps API v2.
Can someone tell me if it is possible to download and store map tiles and map data for different areas of the map to be used offline. 
The ideal usage for this would be to be able to download the whole of the UK, store it on an SD card and then have my app look on the SD for the relevant map data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525822/offline-mode-for-android-app-using-google-maps-api). According to that answer, it is possible with Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: I have the custom tiles, need to show them but getTile() does not get called on the first launch. I need to show custom tiles on first launch in airplane mode. can somebody help? @Agil

Answer (score 1):

The answer pointed by Agil is for the case where you have your own TileProvider (i.e. you own the data). If you have access to the tiles, then yes, that is the right solution for you.

If you were thinking of downloading Google Maps tiles, then no, the API currently doesn't provide a way to download tiles for offline usage; only the one rendered on screen are cached.