# Google Maps API - Drawing Polylines offline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline, offline-mode

I am creating an application, and I haved the coordinates to draw the polylines I need, but I want to draw those polylines when I am offline to show where the user is on the route via GPS. Is it possible? I have read about OSMAND but I am already using Google Maps in the app I am developing and I would like to keep it like that.

Comment: But you have to be online to show the google maps right...?

Comment: That's the point, I know I need to be online, but I know that google has something to save maps on its own app. So I need to know if it is available in the Android API too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525822/offline-mode-for-android-app-using-google-maps-api
This might be helpfull

Comment: Try this link : [Map Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay#add), there might be some mechanism for saving these tiles.