# Raspberry PI and Android communications using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

Currently doing a project using RPI and Android. I would like to display markers (stored on the RPI) in the phone's browser. To do so I need the google maps API but I would like to avoid using data. I have the corresponding map of the marker's location downloaded on the phone (for offline use). Is there a way for using it via the browser?

If not is it possible to place markers on the map in Google maps app(with a sync every 10 sec)?

If it isn't possible either, is it possible to use the offline map in a self-created app?

Comment: `I would like to display markers (stored on the RPI) in the phone's browser.` Pretty unclear what you want. Where would the raspi transfer it markers to?

Comment: This feels like 3 or 4 questions loaded into 1: **marker's location downloaded on the phone (for offline use). Is there a way for using it via the browser?**,  **is it possible to place markers on the map in Google maps app(with a sync every 10 sec)?**,  **is it possible to use the offline map in a self-created app?**

Comment: No the communication is established and using wifi I am able to display markers (i use the online google API). Now I would like to use everything offline. Is it possible to use an offline map (google map app) in the browser or in another app?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use an offline map (google map app) in the browser
>   or in another app?

You can certainly use the Google Maps offline. Here are the following steps indicated in [Download areas and navigate offline](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en):

**Download an area to use offline**

Note: You can store your offline areas on your device or an SD card. If you change the way you store your offline areas, you’ll have to download your offline areas again.

1. On your phone or tablet, open the Google Maps app Google Maps.
2. Make sure you're connected to the Internet and signed in to Google Maps.
3. Search for a place, like San Francisco.
4. At the bottom, tap the name or address of the place. If you search for a place like a restaurant, tap More More.
5. Select Download.

**Use offline areas**

After you download an area, use the Google Maps app just like you normally would.

- Get directions and see routes
- Use navigation
- Search for locations

If your Internet connection is slow or absent, you'll see a lightning bolt and Google Maps will use your offline areas to give you directions.

Also, check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525822/offline-mode-for-android-app-using-google-maps-api) for further reading on using offline Google maps.