# Is there native maps api for android?

Tags: android, xamarin

I am looking for native android maps api to plot the map markers and to plot the path between two markers using xamarin.
I have done this at present using Google Maps api but my client seems to be not happy with using Google maps. Client seems to be thinking that Google maps API works only when we have active internet connection and does not work offline and the NATIVE ANDROID API works offline too.

I am not quite sure about clients thinking but I am unable to find any native maps api. All the tutorials and articles are using Google maps.

Comment: maybe you need to take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525822/offline-mode-for-android-app-using-google-maps-api

but android use google maps i mean they are kind of native maps here ?

Comment: @Umair, so there is no other native android Maps  api?

Comment: No,there isn't. Android system doesn't have any information about geographic infos, it can only get the info through online services.