# how can I use maps completely offline?

Tags: android

I need to make an android app which will show some specific places in a map. and I want to use GPS for tracking user place and showing him the direction. but I want to assume that there is no Internet access at all because I want my application works completely offline. 
which map i have to use and how ?

I appreciate any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want to assume that there is no Internet access at all because I want my application works completely offline. which map i have to use and how ?

There may be ways to use OpenStreetMap's OSMDroid library and package its map tiles with the app. The only apps I have used with OSMDroid have downloaded tiles after the app was installed, perhaps due to size.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Api v2 or v3 is ideal.

See the accepted answer here:

[Using the android Google Maps API v2 as a viewer of offline tiles: is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056156/using-the-android-google-maps-api-v2-as-a-viewer-of-offline-tiles-is-it-possibl)

Always search Google for answers first. A simple search "Google Maps api using offline android" showed me the above link as the first result!

Comment: The question you link to is for *not* using Google's tiles, but rather one's own, and I see nothing in the OP's question to suggest that the OP wishes to replace Google's tiles.