# Using Google Maps Android v2 offline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an app to will sometimes get side loaded onto devices that will never have internet connectivity.  I am already using google maps android v2 throughout the app and would like to continue using it.  In the case of no connectivity I have a set of offline maps installed on the device.

However google seems to require you to connect to the internet at least once to verify the API key before using the maps API.  Even if you set the mapType to NONE google will still not let you place offline tile overlays on the map, nor map markers.  This still seems to be true:
[Using the android Google Maps API v2 as a viewer of offline tiles: is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056156/using-the-android-google-maps-api-v2-as-a-viewer-of-offline-tiles-is-it-possibl)

Does anyone know of any kind of workaround in which I can still use the API and display offline tiles if I have never connected to the internet?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is a feature that wasn't allowed until v7. But I very well could be mistaken, and if so, would love to know the workaround myself

Comment: Talking android API specifically which is at v2.