# google map cache for offline use

Tags: android, google-maps, caching, offline

**Intro**

i have my android app which gets you places address and other info when clicked on a point . and also it can create routing between two points.

**Problem**

the problem is that it only works online . so lets take a case when the user is offline and he want routing then the app is useless.

**Requirement**

i want my app to cache the map of the area the user is currently in and use this as backup when required.

**References**

i got some reference from stackoverflow about the tileprovider in andorid. but it is too small for me to able to understand as i am beginner . i want elaborated suggestion how do i add this functionality to my app .
i want to add this to my google maps fragment . dont want to use any 3rd party lib .

please do suggest .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create your own [tileprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles) and access tiles locally. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056156/using-the-android-google-maps-api-v2-as-a-viewer-of-offline-tiles-is-it-possibl) might help.

Comment: any complete example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is the [sample app](https://github.com/mapsme/api-android/tree/master/sample-app-capitals). It shows one or more points on offline map