# Use google maps offline maps (cache) in Google Maps Android API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google Maps offers for a few months the feature to download a certain geographic region for later offline use. I use **Google Maps Android API** in my App and I see that while offline, in contrast to the real google maps app, I cannot zoom in to street level in my App fully, so the downloaded data is probably not used.

Is there a way for my app to make use of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create your own [`TileProvider`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) and access tiles locally. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay).

Here are some related threads that may help you:

- [Using the android Google Maps API v2 as a viewer of offline tiles: is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056156/using-the-android-google-maps-api-v2-as-a-viewer-of-offline-tiles-is-it-possibl)
- [Offline mode for android app using google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525822/offline-mode-for-android-app-using-google-maps-api)
- [TileProvider using local tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles)

Check this [video tutorial about caching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtWWt2blDTg) and this [example from GitHub](https://github.com/mapsme/api-android).

You can also use [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) which is a replacement for Android's MapView class. It also includes a modular tile provider system with support for numerous online and offline tile sources and overlay support with built-in overlays for plotting icons, tracking location, and drawing shapes. Here is the [tutorial](http://datamoil.blogspot.com/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html).

```
org.osmdroid.views.MapView mapView = (org.osmdroid.views.MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view); //resolve the map view by id given in the layout
mapView.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("Google Maps", ResourceProxy.string.unknown, 1, 20, 256, ".png", "http://mt3.google.com/vt/v=w2.97") {   
    @Override
    public String getTileURLString(final MapTile aTile) {
        /*
         * GOOGLE MAPS URL looks like
         *  base url        const   x   y    zoom
         * http://mt3.google.com/vt/v=w2.97&x=74327&y=50500&z=17
         */
        return getBaseUrl() + "&x=" + aTile.getX() + "&y=" + aTile.getY() + "&z=" + aTile.getZoomLevel();
    }
});
mapView.setUseDataConnection(false); //this actually makes the controller use only offline tiles
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this against the terms of use of Google Maps API? Some discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage