# How to reduce google maps v2 mobile data usage?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i am building an app like uber, in my application when rider was moving to path, i update the marker to new position like uber, the question is how can i reduce data usage by google map, as marker moves to new position map downloads the new information on current position, i have set zoom level to 15.

can any one suggest anything which will reduce the data usage?

Thank you

Comment: One of possible way of reducing mobile data usage is use local map tiles cache. For details take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38177104/6950238) answer. Also read carefully Google Maps APIs Terms of Service, especially p. [10.5 Intellectual Property Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms-20180207#10-license-restrictions).